# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'beanName' available as request attribute

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm an beginner in Spring MVC and I can't figure out why I keep getting the same error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'articleName' available as request
>   attribute

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

JSP code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add article</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add article</h1>

    <c:url var="viewArticlesUrl" value="/articles.htm"/>
    <a href="${viewArticlesUrl}">Show all Articles</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <c:url var="saveArticleUrl" value="/articles/save.htm"/>
<from:form modelAttribute="article" method="POST" action="${saveArticleUrl}">
    <form:label path="articleName">Article name:</form:label>
    <form:input path="articleName"/>       
    <br />
    <form:label path="articleDesc">Article Desc:</form:label>
    <form:textarea path="articleDesc" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save Article" />
</from:form>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/articles")
    public class ArticleController {

@Autowired
private ArticleService articleService;

@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("article")Article article, BindingResult result){
    articleService.addArticle(article);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listArticles(){
    Map<String, Object> model=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("articles", articleService.listArticles());

    return new ModelAndView("articlesList", model);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article, BindingResult result){
    return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
}
}
```

Dispatcher:

```
     <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="articles.htm">articleController</prop>
            <prop key="articles/add.htm">articleController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->

 <bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<!-- article controller -->
<bean name="articleController" class="controller.ArticleController"/>
```

```
           @Entity
   @Table(name="article")
  public class Article {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="article_id")
private Long articleId;

@Column(name="article_name", nullable=false, length=20)
private String articleName;

@Column(name="article_desc", nullable=false)
private String articleDesc;

@Column(name="date_added")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date addedDate;

  public Article() {    
  }

  public Long getArticleId() {
    return articleId;
  }

  public void setArticleId(Long articleId) {
    this.articleId = articleId;
  }

  public String getArticleName() {
    return articleName;
  }

  public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
  }

  public String getArticleDesc() {
    return articleDesc;
  }

  public void setArticleDesc(String articleDesc) {
    this.articleDesc = articleDesc;
  }

  public Date getAddedDate() {
    return addedDate;
  }

  public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
    this.addedDate = addedDate;
  }
```

}

I'm getting the problem: when i do a GET request

Comment: For your object (defined in your form as modelAttribute) "Article", does it have "articleName" property as you have defined in your <form:input path="articleName"/> ?

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post your Article object code here and if you can clarify whether you are getting the error during GET or POST.

Comment: Try this for your addArticle:

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article, BindingResult result, ModelMap map){
    map.put("article", article");
    return new ModelAndView("addArticle", map);
}

Comment: Still got the same error. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmmm..have you tried removing BindingResult result?

Comment: found it, I'm so stupid.
I feel like I wasted you time.
it's all in my jsp.
It is:
<form:label path="articleName">Article name:</form:label>
<form:input path="articleName"/> 
it should be:
<form:label path="article.articleName">Article name:</form:label>
<form:input path="article.articleName"/>

I'm so sorry for wasting your time
Thanks for everything, It's thanks to you I found the problem

Comment: Glad you found the solution! Enjoy the feeling!!

Answer (score 2):

It is proven I'm stupid

It is:

```
  <form:label path="articleName">Article name:</form:label> 
  <form:input path="articleName"/>
```

it should be:

```
  <form:label path="article.articleName">Article name:</form:label> 
  <form:input path="article.articleName"/>
```

same for articleDesc

Let's be honest, I found the solution thanks to: Stealth

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("On Submit");

        ModelAndView mv = super.onSubmit(command, errors);
        mv.addObject("result","success");
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: could you add some context to your answer?